# "Configuration system failed to initialize" while initializing a New TcpClient

Tags: vb.net, service, tcpclient

I'm devoloping a windows service which requires a socket connection to my server to do its job. I made the service establish the connection through a thread that is started on the OnStart service's event. It worked until this morning when I've compiled it again after some changes I've made: it crashes on the initialization of the client variable. Here is the part of the code where it crashes:

```
Try
            client = New TcpClient 'the error is here
            client.Connect(ip, port)
            stream = client.GetStream()
            receiver.Start()
            tryingconnect_thread.Abort()
        Catch ex As Exception
            File.WriteAllText("C:\error.txt", ex.Message) 'here it gives me "Configuration system failed to initialize"
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000)
End Try
```

To be sure I also tried the Try Catch End Try statements only with the initialization in it.
How can I solve this problem?

I've already seen other questions like this, but none of them worked.

EDIT:

This is the exception:

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Impossibile inizializzare il sistema di configurazione ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Sezione di configurazione authentication non riconosciuta. (C:\Users\Davide\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\winddsvc\winddsvc\bin\Debug\winddsvc.exe.Config line 8)
in System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors.ThrowIfErrors(Boolean ignoreLocal)
in System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfParseErrors(ConfigurationSchemaErrors schemaErrors)
in System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfInitErrors()
in System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(String configKey)
--- Fine della traccia dello stack dell'eccezione interna ---
in System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(String configKey)
in System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.PrepareClientConfigSystem(String sectionName)
in System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection(String sectionName)
in System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
in System.Configuration.PrivilegedConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
in System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticsConfiguration.GetConfigSection()
in System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticsConfiguration.Initialize()
in System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticsConfiguration.get_Sources()
in System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.Initialize()
in System.Net.Logging.InitializeLogging()
in System.Net.Logging.get_On()
in System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient..ctor(AddressFamily family)
in System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient..ctor()
in winddsvc.winddsvc.tryconnect() in C:\Users\Davide\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\winddsvc\winddsvc\Service1.vb:riga 88
```

And this is the config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

    <startup> 
         <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>

    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <identity impersonate="true" />
</configuration>
```

Comment: If you abort threads all bets are off. This can destabilize the entire process.

Comment: I know, but that isn't the problem

Comment: I know VB.NET is sloppy regarding `()` sometimes, but have you tried `client = new TcpClient()`?  Based on the error message, I'd take a look at your config file to see if something is off there.

Comment: Provide the entire exception.

Comment: @Tim I've already tried but nothing changed. Now there is the config file.

Comment: @usr Here you are. P.S. = something is written in Italian.

Comment: The message points you to a file, section and line. Are you sure there is no error at that location?

Comment: @usr There is <authentication mode="Windows" />. Is this config file correct?

Comment: No. Look at the official schema documentation. There is no such element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just found the solution: simply remove the

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<identity impersonate="true" />
```

part from the config file.